# Calling different environments depending on a variable

Tags: macros, environments

I would like to use a different environment depending on situations.

I tried the following but it does not work. Can you help me understanding what's wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newenvironment{testA}{\bfseries}{}
\newenvironment{testB}{\itshape}{}

\def\someVariable{1}

\def\variableName
{\ifthenelse{\equal{\someVariable}{1}}
        {testA}
        {testB}}

\begin{document}

\begin{\variableName}
Some text.
\end{\variableName}

\end{document}
```

---

EDIT

My goal is to define an `tcolorbox` environment whose background color would depend on another variable.

Comment: Probably a better idea to explain what your actual end goal is? Often there are different ways to solve them

Comment: IMO your edit is still a bit vague. Your construct doesn't work because `\ifthenelse` performs token assignments, and that breaks down in `\csname...\endcsname`. Will `\someVariable` always be just a number? Will be an arbitrary string?

Comment: So for your `tcolorbox`-environment you need mapping from possible "value" of the "variable" to background-color-specification? More precise specification of the problem is needed: What constellations of tokens are to form the "value" of the "variable"? What role does expansion play with such constellations of tokens? Is it about mapping from values of TeX-<number>-quantities to color-specifications? What to do in what contexts in case a variable-value for some reason cannot be mapped to a color-specification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\variableName` needs to be expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{testA}{\bfseries}{}
\newenvironment{testB}{\itshape}{}


\def\variableName{\ifnum\someVariable=1 testA\else testB\fi}

\begin{document}

\def\someVariable{1}
\begin{\variableName}
Some text.
\end{\variableName}

\def\someVariable{2}
\begin{\variableName}
Some text.
\end{\variableName}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted to compare strings, rather than numbers, you could do the following with an `\ifx` comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{testA}{\bfseries}{}
\newenvironment{testB}{\itshape}{}

\def\testAname{testA}

\def\variableName{\ifx\someVariable\testAname testA\else testB\fi}

\begin{document}

\def\someVariable{testA}
\begin{\variableName}
Some text.
\end{\variableName}

\def\someVariable{testB}
\begin{\variableName}
Some text.
\end{\variableName}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Might as well delete the `ifthen` package in this case?

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for combing the detritus.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably better solutions, but here's one option the pretty much follows the logic of your original attempt.

(Quick explanation: as [campa said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603361/calling-different-environments-depending-on-a-variable/603376#comment1513356_603361), you shouldn't do the conditional parsing within the argument of the `\begin{...}...\end{...}`. One way to work around it is to use `\expandafters`, but that's clunky in your main latex code. Better way is to offload the conditional comparison to be done by the set-up code for a wrapper environment.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newenvironment{testA}{\bfseries}{}
\newenvironment{testB}{\itshape}{}

\def\someVariable{1}

\newenvironment{testQ}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\someVariable}{1}}{\def\variableName{testA}}{\def\variableName{testB}}%
    \expandafter\begin\expandafter{\variableName}}
    {\expandafter\end\expandafter{\variableName}}

\begin{document}

\begin{testQ}
Some text.
\end{testQ}

\def\someVariable{2}

\begin{testQ}
        More text
\end{testQ}

\end{document}
```

The `if-then-else` logic would be easier to write if you use the [`environ`](https://ctan.org/pkg/environ?lang=en) package instead to program the `testQ` environment. To wit:

```
\usepackage{environ}

...


\NewEnviron{testQ}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\someVariable}{1}}
    {\begin{testA}\BODY\end{testA}}
    {\begin{testB}\BODY\end{testB}}}
```

which I think is a bit more readable and also easier to write.

Answer (score 2):

:-)   This is my two cents:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newenvironment{dependingOnSomeVariablesValue}
{\ifthenelse{\equal{\someVariable}{1}}{\testA}{\testB}}
{\ifthenelse{\equal{\someVariable}{1}}{\endtestA}{\endtestB}}

\newenvironment{testA}{\bfseries}{FinishTestA}
\newenvironment{testB}{\itshape}{FinishTestB}

\begin{document}

\def\someVariable{1}

\begin{dependingOnSomeVariablesValue}
Some text.
\end{dependingOnSomeVariablesValue}

\def\someVariable{XYZ}

\begin{dependingOnSomeVariablesValue}
Some text.
\end{dependingOnSomeVariablesValue}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Drawbacks/pitfalls:**

Don't globally change the definition/the "value" of `\someVariable` from within the `dependingOnSomeVariablesValue`-environment. :-)

With error-messages about improperly nested environments `\@currenvir` will denote the phrase "dependingOnSomeVariablesValue" instead of "testA" or "testB".

---

---

Another possibility could be using `\pdfstrcmp`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{testA}{\bfseries}{}
\newenvironment{testB}{\itshape}{}

\newcommand\variableName{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\someVariable}{1}=0 testA\else testB\fi}
%\newcommand\variableName{test\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\someVariable}{1}=0 A\else B\fi}

\begin{document}

\def\someVariable{1}

\begin{\variableName}
Some text.
\end{\variableName}

\def\someVariable{XYZ}

\begin{\variableName}
Some text.
\end{\variableName}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Drawbacks/pitfalls:**

Don't globally change the definition/the "value" of `\someVariable` from within the `\variableName`-"environment". :-)